# [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Unexpected token 'A', 'An error o'... is not valid JSON."

Tags: session, next.js, vercel, next-auth

I'm facing an issue with my code where it works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it to Vercel, I encounter the following error:

"GET https://mug-e-commerce-project.vercel.app/api/auth/session 504"

"[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Unexpected token 'A', 'An error o'... is not valid JSON."

Here are some details regarding my setup:

- I'm using Next.js 13.4.4 and NextAuth 4.22.1.

- GitHub link to my code: [GitHub](https://github.com/yee882408/Mug-e-commerce-project)

- Website link: [Website](https://mug-e-commerce-project.vercel.app/)

In Vercel, I have already configured the necessary environment variables, including NEXTAUTH_URL, NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL, and NEXTAUTH_SECRET.

Upon reviewing the GET request to "/api/auth/session," I noticed that when I run the code locally without logging in, it returns an empty object ({}). However, after deploying to Vercel, it consistently results in a 504 error after approximately 30 seconds. I suspect this issue may be related to limitations imposed by Vercel itself.

I have made efforts to ensure that the Vercel server is located in the same place as the MongoDB server, but unfortunately, the problem persists.

I've been struggling with this issue for a week now, and I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

[504Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjTIz.png)

[504Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIzz5.png)

[504Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ6hT.png)

[504Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvlOL.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have same issue, did you figure it out?